# how to pass parameters from one state to other using angular2 ui router form ts code?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular2-routing, angular2-services

I am new to Angular2 . I tried quickstart application.same application now I want to do with angular2 ui router,I am struckking here

I have some list Items. When I click one Item it shows details of that item in that page only , there I have one button(MoreDetais). If user click that button
it should be redirect to item detail page.This state required item id.

I am using angular2-ui-router.(just like stateprovider in angular1)

with that I am able to change state by doing

Ts:

```
import {UIRouter} from "ui-router-ng2";

constructor(private _uiRouter:UIRouter){}

gotoDetail(): void {
//this._uiRouter.stateService.go('app.heroesdetail');// its working
// this._uiRouter.stateService.go('app.heroesdetail',{this.selectedHero.id})
}
```

Html:

```
<ul class="heroes">
  <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes"[class.selected]="hero === selectedHero"
   (click)="onSelect(hero)">
     <span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span> {{hero.name}}
        <button class="delete" (click)="delete(hero);     $event.stopPropagation()">x</button>
  </li>
</ul>
   <div *ngIf="selectedHero">
     <h2>
         {{selectedHero.name | uppercase}} is my hero
     </h2>
     <button (click)="gotoDetail()">View Details</button>
   </div>
```

Please help me?

Comment: can you share how you have configure your state ?

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution , Just I did silly thing

Before

```
   gotoDetail(): void {
this._uiRouter.stateService.go('app.heroesdetail',{this.selectedHero.id})
```

}

Now

```
gotoDetail(): void {
     this._uiRouter.stateService.go('app.heroesdetail',{id:this.selectedHero.id})
```

}

it's working

Answer (score -1):

just use `navigateByUrl` or `navigate` methods of router to navigate from one state to another also you are able to pass parameters too with navigatation like this

```
this.router.navigate(['Route_path',this.selectedHero.id]);
```

or by using `navigateByUrl` like this,

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('/Route_path',this.selectedHero.id);
```

For more info on routing and navigation you can read here

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

Comment: I know this solution , I  want to do with ui router

Comment: But there is nothing related to `ui-router` in angular2 its from angular 1, i think @SoumyaGangamwar

Comment: it' s not working, Because I change my routes to states,

Comment: so what , i suggest you two methods to navigate with params, nd also according to angular2, i dont think my answer should be downvoted. as you did